# Leverage browser caching (expiration not specified)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Changes in htaccess Expires header not working

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>


# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

I am using Google page speed insights to improve the performance but no matter what I do I can't get the 'leverage browser caching' to disappear.

Comment: If your files are form another server then it will  not work...

Comment: This code is enough for LBC `# One month for most static assets
 <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|svg)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
 </filesMatch>`